# cytoscape js, how define node with background-image from a json data file

Tags: json, graph, cytoscape.js

I want use cytoscape librairy for build a sample graphs but I want display on each node different images.

I tried that :

```
[ 
  {
    "data": [
      "id0"
    ],
    "position": {
      "x": 44,
      "y": 93
    }
  },
  {
    "data": [
      "id1"
    ],
    "position": {
      "x": 77,
      "y": 200
    },
    "background-image": [
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/High_above_the_Cloud_the_Sun_Stays_the_Same.jpg",
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Pigeon_silhouette_4874.svg/1000px-Pigeon_silhouette_4874.svg.png"
    ],
    "background-fit": "cover cover",
    "background-image-opacity": 0.5
  }
]
```

But when I load my page I see two 'empty' nodes. I used this javascript script :

```
fetch('data.json', {mode: 'no-cors'})
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json()
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
      container: document.getElementById('cy'),

      layout: {
        name: 'preset',
      },

      style: [
        {
          selector: 'node',
          style: {
            'height': 20,
            'width': 20,
          }
        }
      ],

      elements: data
    });
  });
```

Where is my mistake ? How can I generate a graph with different background images on each nodes ?

Thanks you :)

Comment: Remove `{mode: 'no-cors'}`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I removed {mode: 'no-cors'} but nothing change.. :/

Comment: What do you see in the browser console and any issues in Network tab?

Comment: I checked that and there are no errors (firefog native debugger, nothing appears in network and console tab with my code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my solution:
https://plnkr.co/edit/lKjxkMS8F1E68Mk70fjS?p=preview

It is important set to css for *#cy*.

```
#cy {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

EDIT:
This is correct -> https://plnkr.co/edit/lKjxkMS8F1E68Mk70fjS?p=preview

It is necessarily "background-image" wrap tag "style".

```
"style": {
  "background-image": [
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/High_above_the_Cloud_the_Sun_Stays_the_Same.jpg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Pigeon_silhouette_4874.svg/1000px-Pigeon_silhouette_4874.svg.png"
  ],
  "background-fit": "cover cover",
  "background-image-opacity": 0.5
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! but...the background image does not appear in the second node when I go to your plnkr link (https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/862748backgroundimage.png). I may not have been clear.(my english skills..) , in my data.json file you can see I have defined a node with a background image. I'm looking for a way for display a background image (defined from the data.json file) on a node. I tried follow the example in the cytoscape's doc (http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/background-image) but my tries does not work :/

Comment: I added answer. I think, That is correct. Check it, please!